Specify a program as default for all types it supports at once
I want a simple command or method that lets me set (in top priority) a program as default for all file types it supports.
I don't want any solution where I have to go manually one-by-one on every mime type, like in related answers. This is important specially for apps that deal with media (audio, video) as there are a zillion different formats.
The specific problem
I had VLC as a player for both video and audio. But when I installed the Tenacity flatpak, it set itself as default for audio files. A similar issue happened before with a video editor. This is stupid, as I obviously want to play (not edit) a file when I double-click it. I never went on any option inside Tenacity to make it default for anything, I literally just installed it.
This is one of the few things Windows does much better than Kubuntu, as I remember there's a way to set the default program both per-extension as well as set it for all extensions supported by the program. I could be mistaken, but Windows seems to also have an Android-like "intent" system, where it makes a distinction between e.g. "opening" a file or "editing" a file generically, and each of these actions could be associated with a specific program? Well, this doesn't seem to be the case in Kubuntu, and I can only find answers that apply to individual file/mime types.
Anyway, in System Settings, we have the Applications > File Associations which would be what I want (I can easily reorder program priority for each individual mime-type), except I have to go one-by-one.
And the Applications > Default Applications is not like in Windows; it's too limited, so it's useless for what I need. I want to select any app, not just those listed.
The solution I want

A command, editable file, or preferably some setting UI where I input just the program I want as default for everything it supports. If I want any exceptions, these should be doable later via the usual method, or else please tell me how.
Ideally just set some "program override" file or whatever, without having to list all mime types, so it would implicitly work for all types it supports, e.g. across updates (let's say app updates add/remove file types, or apps are installed later, then I don't want to have to re-run this solution).

If this is not possible, and it has to create/change overrides for every mime type, it does so automatically for all types supported by the program.


I run multiple users, so I'd like the option to do it system-wide.
I hope I don't have to uninstall and reinstall the program I want as default (VLC in this case). Would that even work?

Is there a built-in system like this implemented in Linux?
If not, what are the workarounds? Thanks in advance.

Strangely it seems my specific problem fixed itself? I didn't do anything (except reboot I guess) and VLC was back at the top, as the default app instead of Tenacity. I don't think either of them updated, even? Anyway, I'll leave the question open because it's still a valid question.
